# How can I install C++ man pages manually?

Tags: linux, man

Sadly, `yum install  libstdc++-docs` doesn't work for me:

```
No package libstdc++-docs available.
```

So, I can only install it myself.

I've found the C++ man pages [here](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/libstdc++/doxygen/libstdc++-api.20140403.man.tar.bz2), how can I install it?

I guess just put it under `/usr/share/man/man3` will do the job, but I'm not sure...

Any tips?

**UPDATE**

Anyone knows how to install c+ man pages manually(no yum,no rpm)?

Comment: have you tried `yum search` to see if you have a typo in the package name?

Comment: @Didier Trosset ,I did,but no luck.

Comment: which distribution are you using, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Debian so the package names may be diffent, but you might as well give it a try:

```
robin@Robin-Latitude-D620 ~ $ aptitude search libstdc++
v   libstdc++-dev                   -                                           
v   libstdc++-dev-armel-cross       -                                           
v   libstdc++-dev-armel-dcv1        -                                           
p   libstdc++5                      - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3           
i   libstdc++6                      - De GNU stdc++ bibliotheek versie 3        
p   libstdc++6-4.3-dbg              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging
p   libstdc++6-4.3-dev              - De GNU Standaard C++ bibliotheek v3 (voor 
p   libstdc++6-4.3-doc              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documenta
p   libstdc++6-4.3-pic              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared li
p   libstdc++6-4.4-dbg              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging
p   libstdc++6-4.4-dbg-armel-cross  - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging
i A libstdc++6-4.4-dev              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (developme
p   libstdc++6-4.4-dev-armel-cross  - De GNU Standaard C++ bibliotheek v3 (voor 
p   libstdc++6-4.4-doc              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documenta
p   libstdc++6-4.4-pic              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared li
p   libstdc++6-4.4-pic-armel-cross  - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared li
p   libstdc++6-4.5-dbg              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging
p   libstdc++6-4.5-dbg-armel-cross  - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging
p   libstdc++6-4.5-dev              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (developme
p   libstdc++6-4.5-dev-armel-cross  - De GNU Standaard C++ bibliotheek v3 (voor 
p   libstdc++6-4.5-doc              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (documenta
p   libstdc++6-4.5-pic              - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared li
p   libstdc++6-4.5-pic-armel-cross  - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared li
p   libstdc++6-armel-cross          - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3           
v   libstdc++6-armel-dcv1           -                                           
v   libstdc++6-dbg-armel-dcv1       -                                           
v   libstdc++6-dev-armel-dcv1       -                                           
v   libstdc++6-pic-armel-dcv1
```

I think libstdc++6-4.5-doc might be what you're looking for? Maybe the package name is the same in your distro's repositories?

Anyway, I don't know *yum* very well (only used it twice), but if I remember correctly, it's got a *search* command as well, just like aptitude has.
Doesn't *yum search libstdc++* give you anything useful?

--

Found something that's probably more useful to you: ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/releases/15/Everything/i386/os/Packages/libstdc++-docs-4.6.0-6.fc15.i686.rpm

Found it here: http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B-docs

Comment: @RobinJ,that rpm doesn't work for me,as mine is fc6,pretty old..

Comment: Uhm... fc6? Fedora Core 6, you mean?
These RPM packages seem to be for Fedora 6: http://www.icewalkers.com/rpm/libstdc%2B%2B/fedora-core-6/download/libstdc%2B%2B-24975.html

Comment: @ RobinJ,right.Let me try it:)

Comment: @ RobinJ,non of the links work:( I think the only option is to install those man pages manually...

Comment: I downloaded the libstdc++6-4.5-doc package from the Ubuntu repositories (aptitude download libstdc++6-4.5-doc), extracted it, removed unneeded files, and packed it together again. If you just put the files in the corresponding directories on your filesystem, it should work I expect.
Uploading...

Comment: Yay! Finally! Here you go, hope this works: http://www.multiupload.com/UT3NPSTL4U

Answer (score 1):

cppreference.com has [archives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives).

in order to install the [man pages](https://github.com/jeaye/stdman) (git), one can do the following :

```
git clone https://github.com/jeaye/stdman.git
cd stdman
./configure
sudo make install
```

by default, the man pages are now located at

```
/usr/local/share/man/man3
```

EDIT: 
after `mandb` has run, one can do `man std::cout`